# Relationship between Weak Cosmic Censorship and Topological Censorship

Tags: gravity, research-level, topology, singularities, cosmic-censorship

The weak cosmic censorship states that any singularity cannot be in the causual past of null infinity [(reference)](http://prd.aps.org/pdf/PRD/v47/i10/p4362_1).

The topological censorship hypothesis states that in a globally hyperbolic, asymptotically flat spacetime, every causal curve from $J^-$ to $J^+$ is homotopic to a topological trivial curve between the two points.  [(reference)](http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9305017)

I am curious as to the relationship between these two; will a found violation of weak cosmic censorship necessarily mean a violation of topological censorship? [edit: or the converse]

Comment: BTW, isn't it a bit ironic to cite a paper with the words "Strong cosmic censorship" in the title as your reference to weak cosmic censorship?

Comment: I was originally going to try to make a case relating Strong cosmic censorship to Topological censorship, but I decided I was more interested in weak censorship anyway :P That paper has a concise definition though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No.

Firstly, weak cosmic censorship can only hold in the *generic* sense, as there are known examples of nakedly singular space-times. (See, e.g. [Christodoulou 1993](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/cpa.3160460803), and [Christodoulou 1999](http://www.jstor.org/stable/121023).)

Observe in particular that the nakedly singular space-time constructed in the 1993 paper is spherically symmetric with a central axis, and the initial data is prescribed on a set homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$. So the maximal globally hyperbolic development of this data, which leads to a naked singularity (hence violating cosmic censorship), is simply connected (homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^4$ actually). And hence must satisfy topological censorship.

---

BTW, if the implication you want were actually true, then given that nakedly singular solutions are known in the literature, it would be rather difficult to have topological censorship be a proven theorem in the generality that it is usually stated.

---

However, it is interesting to note that the converse (or something quite close to it) of the statement you are interested in actually holds. By a result of [Galloway and Woolgar](http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9609007) you have that, roughly speaking: weak cosmic censorship + null energy condition implies topological censorship. The contrapositive of which would say that *failure* of topological censorship + null energy condition holding will imply weak cosmic censorship is false.